# php_printer.dll installation doesn't work

Tags: php, dll, printing, php-extension

I am trying to install `php_printer.dll` in my localhost powered by wampserver with `Apache ver(2.4.9)` for `Win64` and `PHP(5.5.12)`.
I copied my `php_printer.dll` to ext directory and added `extension=php_printer.dll` to the end of my php.ini but the extension doesn't show up on my extension list.
I got the `php_printer.dll` from `php_printer-0.1.0-dev-5.5-ts-vc11-x64.`

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Have you checked php_info()? Have you turned error reporting on?

Comment: yes, error reporting is on.

Comment: What about php_info(), this will tell you if the extension is being loaded or not.

Comment: No, it was not loaded, but I found the solution. It works now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. you have to use the same `VC` version of your apache pack

Comment: Can you please explain some more on the solution as I am also stucked at same point

Comment: @AjitHogade you need to find out what version of `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` your `apache` uses. then find the same version of `php_printer.dll` compiled with. if you are trying to install it on a `wamp` or `xampp` find out which version of `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` or in short `vc_redist.x86.exe` or `vc_redist.x64.exe` is used in your version of `wamp` or `xampp`